# Have anyone implemented Load more paging in android with JSON parser ?

Tags: android, json, android-json

I wanna implement a load more pagination in android for my listview with JSON Parser.
I got one tutorial but its with XML parser from here.

**http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/**

Any ideas how to do that with JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Url: /list?page=1

The first time: you execute above URL. If there is no item more, you should *disable* your button "Load More" else, you show button "Load More" and when user clicks to Button "Load More", you will execute url with page=2, ...

After execute, you should add items to your **ListView Adapter** and call **notifyDataSetChange()**